# Typo3 8.7.x / Extbase / Typoscript: How to remove the anchor wrap when using RECORDS

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I'm using an extension template for json output. I want to get the record by id.

```
ajax = PAGE
ajax {
  typeNum = 99
  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
  }
  10 = RECORDS
  10 {
    tables = tt_content
    source = 77
  }
}
```

But my output has an anchor link before the data I want:

```
<a id="c2"></a>{"errors":[],"messages":["some message"]}
```

How to remove the

```
<a id="c2"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Bernd Wilke,
now it's working with the following code

```
ajax = PAGE
ajax {
  typeNum = 99
  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
  }
  //not working, because it's not respect the storage
  #10 < tt_content.list.20.myext_p1
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = tt_content   
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
      10 < tt_content.list.20.myext_p1
    }
  }
}
```

When I'm right, with this code, it takes the content from the page from the page where the ext Template is defined and copies the rendering from the plugin. The uncommented code is not working because it's not using the content from the page where I inserted my plugin with the defined storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `RECORDS` object you will get the default rendering of the records. And for tt_content that might include the anchor which is wrapped before for each element.

If you want your own rendering you can use a `CONTENT` object with your own `renderObj` property.

Or you modify the global rendering of `tt_content` records (either in typoscript for CSC or in the fluid layout file for FSC) to skip the anchor for pagetype 99.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try that. First I have to find out how to get my plugin content with CONTENT and renderObj, becaue the content comes from my plugin.

Comment: normaly you can find the rendering configuration at `tt_content.<CType>` or at `plugins.<list_type>`, which you can copy to the renderObj - and then modify.